# Is Android Service useful when I don't need interprocess communication?

Tags: android, service

It seems that when I don't need interprocess communication, there's almost no reason to use a Service. The only reason I am aware of is this: if my process has a started Service, the process is less likely to be killed.

I could just have a utility class with dontWantToBeKilled() and canBeKilled() methods, which would start / stop a dummy Service. Apart from that, I won't use Services. Is this right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are other reasons.

Your application runs in a process which can be killed by the system whenever it needs more resources.

According to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle) a running service has a higher priority than an Activity that isn't in the foreground, meaning that the system is more likely to kill an application process that has an Activity in the background than one that has a Service running in the background.

The documentation for Service states that:

> [If the service has been started, then its hosting process is
>   considered to be less important than any processes that are currently
>   visible to the user on-screen, but more important than any process not
>   visible. Because only a few processes are generally visible to the
>   user, this means that the service should not be killed except in
>   extreme low memory conditions.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ProcessLifecycle)

So, you can use Services to decrease the likelihood of your application process being killed.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the `Service` runs in the same process as an `Activity` nothing guarantees you that your `Activity` will not be killed.

From [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html):

> For example, an activity that's uploading a picture to a web site
>   should start a service to perform the upload so that the upload can
>   continue in the background even if the user leaves the activity. Using
>   a service guarantees that the operation will have at least "service
>   process" priority, regardless of what happens to the activity. This is
>   the same reason that broadcast receivers should employ services rather
>   than simply put time-consuming operations in a thread.

Conclusion:
If you want to do a background operation that will take a while and it's important it finishes correctly, use a `Service`.

Comment: I know that my Activity can be killed, but the "kill" is just nulling Android's reference to it, so that garbage collector can remove it from memory. Objects with static reference (like singletons) are removed only when the whole process is killed. I think that for long background operations it is often simpler to use a singleton and call dontWantToBeKilled() and canBeKilled() utility methods that start / stop a dummy Service. Android Services is imho a flawed design or a really badly documented design.

Comment: @fhucho: Why would you use a singleton instead of a `Service`?

Comment: There are many things that make working with a Service more complicated an difficult than working with a singleton. I don't have to do asynchronous binding, I don't have to serialize data to startService, I don't have to understand the different flags, startId etc. Singleton is just more simple and straightforward.

Comment: Instead of investing time in setting up the singleton to create/destroy a `Service` you can invest it in learning of how to use the `Service` correctly.

Comment: I understand Services but they are just harder to work with than singletons are. After creating a utility class with dontWantToBeKilled() and canBeKilled() methods I can use simple singletons instead of handling async communication with my Services.

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary that if A process started service then,Process is likely to be killed.Actually process remain alive or not it does not affect  service.As its completely background procedure.May be the situation that you have started a process to just start a service.So process and service can not interrelated like that.

AFAIK i did not got your final question properly.

Comment: I am 90% sure that if my app process is killed, then my Services are killed too.

Comment: If you came outside the application your service will not killed.Look at alarm application alarm service does not depends the application that start it whether open or closed

Comment: What do you mean by "came outside the application"? Alarm app uses Broadcast, not a Service.

Comment: Not entirely true. Alarm apps use BroadcastReceivers, but you can do no real work in those as you will very quickly run into ANR forcecloses. Typically you don't do much more in a BroadcastReceiver's onReceive method than either start a Service or an Activity.

Comment: Let me explain..when you start a downloading using service then its not necessary to stay in app until download complete.But if you came  outside the app, i think download will remain continue.