# Android: Why use Services in more than a dummy capacity when I'm not using IPC?

Tags: android, service

After spending a lot of time trying to figure out what exactly is advantageous about using a Service to perform my background tasks rather than a simple singleton class, the only concrete answer I seem to have found is that the *mere existence* of a started Service will make the system less likely to kill my process.

If this is the case, then what reason is there to actually use any functionality of a Service beyond starting and stopping it to signal that I don't want my process killed at certain times? Rather than deal with the hassle of binding to services, etc., why not use a simple singleton in conjunction with a "setPleaseDontKillMyProcessIfYouCanHelpIt(boolean)" method that starts and stops a dummy service as appropriate? Again, I'm not using inter-process communication, so that functionality doesn't factor in here.

I'm aware that a user asks a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8310364/is-android-service-useful-when-i-dont-need-interprocess-communication), but he doesn't get a straight answer, only a reiteration of the fact that a started Service discourages the system from killing your app (and a suggestion that he "use Services correctly" rather than using singletons and dummy services, but no word as to why).

Thanks in advance for any answers. This is my first time using StackOverflow, so please advise me if I've breached any rules of etiquette.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to figure this out, too. There are several things you might take into consideration, Service:

- allows you to have a loose coupling using Intents (you can limit the
  whole communication process between activities and services to
  intents only)
- can handle intents forwarded by BroadcastReceivers
  (e.g. TIMEZONE_CHANGED)
- allows you to move operations off the main
  thread, if they become time-consuming
- allows you to be aware of the
  application lifecycle - service gets callbacks when it is created or
  stopped

Think of service as an Activity without a GUI. It is as well a lifecycle-managed object  and it can access you Singleton.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that a Service will not be killed by Android, under normal circumstances. Your singleton class may be less likely to get killed if you have a Service, but it will definitely get killed when another app claims the space. What's the reason you don't want to use a service?

Comment: I'm not categorically against using a service, just trying to understand why I should. Since the service is part of the same process as the rest of my program, how can it be that the singleton will be killed while the service won't?

Comment: That's how Android works. When it needs space, and it sees pojos, it will kill them, leaving the services alone. Your pojos (singleton classes) are, one way or the other, part of your activities. When the activities are killed, your pojos are killed, because there's nothing left that has a reference to them. Unless the service has a reference to them, but then, it's the service that is kept alive, and it's pojos with it.